# Getting an error Peer fingerprint did not match after running composer update

Tags: php, composer-php

It's my first time using composer, and I'm planning to use in one of my current projects. I'm getting an error `Peer fingerprint did not match` after running composer update on my terminal/cmd. Does this have something with the composer.json file?

I tried looking for answers on the internet but I cannot seem to find an answer relevant to my problem.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with SSL Certificates and Emulate fingerprint validation on PHP < 5.6:  https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php#L354

Comment: @Potherca: Thanks, this is what happened to me (2 years later!). I had to downgrade composer to an older version (1.2.0) to make it work with an old PHP.

Answer (score 7):

In your command line, run `composer self-update` and try installing the package again. See [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7530). when I did that and reinstalled the package, it worked!